# Can i "echo" the recent news from wordpress site to a subdomain site?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hello i have a wordpress site and a html static site, both are on the same server so the thing i need to do is somehow implement the news from wordpress to the static one, and i find myself lost, how can this be achieved ?

Comment: Please elaborate. Your question is extremely vague.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "static HTML page" as hard-coded `*.html` pages, than it's not possible. If it's php site, just use same database, connect to it with PDO and get needed values

**PDO CONNECT**

```
$db = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db-name",
    $config['components']['db']['username'],
    $config['components']['db']['password']
);

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `news`');
$query->execute();
$tags = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: it's not a problem to create a php page but i would still need help to "use the same database and connect it with PDO to get the needed values"

Comment: @IvanVeselinovNedelchev well, you can google "How to mysql PDO". I updated with partial code from my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [json-api](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin, then get content from json link and echo it in your subdomain site. It's easilest way to get content without connect to another database.